# calling "RequestedTheme" method on visual basic? (Windows Store Apps)

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

On C#, We can call "RequestedTheme" method as follows

```
public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        App.Current.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }
```

Is it possible in vb by coding in "app.xaml.vb" file? (I already know the XAML tag for this, but it is not essential for my project.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not well experienced either in vb or windows store app. But i tried this in App.xaml.vb:

```
Public Sub New()
    Current.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light
End Sub
```

and it works like in c# version, that line of code change application theme from default dark to light. The strange point is vb version of win store apps doesn't have explicit constructor defined for App class. So as you see above, i need to defined the constructor method my self, and put the code there. Apart of is it good practice or not, but the answer is **yes it is possible** to port your c# codes into vb.

Comment: It works! Thank you! But, is it good to add the method ''InitializeComponent()'' into the constructor as it works at the initiation of the app?

Comment: I also not sure about that, but i think InitializeComponent() in vb version is already called somewhere. Because AFAIK, in c# version if you remove InitializeComponent() the UI components/controls will not rendered. And notice in vb version, without adding InitializeComponent() the UI appear fine, thats why I assume it already called somewhere and not added that line in my answer.